# how to give print permission to a windows user account with powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

In a windows computer which have multiple user accounts how is it possible to give print permission to a specific user using powershell?

Thank You.

Comment: Is this a network printer? If so, is the print server hosted on the computer in question? And is the computer domain-joined? Are these local users, Microsoft accounts or Active Directory accounts? What currently happens when the users attempt to print, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: it's not a network printer. printer is plugged in via USB and user accounts are not microsoft accounts they are local accounts. admin account can add, remove printers and print documents but the other local account can't add printer or print. nothing happens when user tries to print.

Comment: By default, everyone can use local printers. What version of Windows are we talking about? Do you have more than one local user account with that problem? What happens with a newly created local account?